# Java nested synchronized

Tags: java, multithreading, synchronized

I have a problem to understand how works the nested synchronized.
i give here 2 examples to make make a comparison:

```
//example 1
public class Account {
    int balance = 1000;
    Object lock = new Object();

    public int getBalance() throws InterruptedException {
        synchronized(lock) {
            // step 1- Thread 1 enter here and sleep
            Thread.sleep(20);
            return balance;
        }
    }
    public void setBalance(int amount) {
        // step 2 - Thread 2 have to wait until thread 1 release the lock.
        synchronized(lock) {
            this.balance = amount;
        }
    }
}
```

the example above is clear and logic.
now look the example 2:

```
public class Account {
    int balance = 1000;
    Object lock = new Object();

    public int getBalance() {
        synchronized(lock) {
            // step 1 - Thread 1 enter here and lock the object.
            synchronized(lock) { //same lock 
                //step 2 - Thread 1 can enter here also if the lock is already locked why????

                //...do something...
                return balance;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

I don't understand in the example 2, why the same thread can enter on the same lock 2 times if the outer lock is already locked...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The inner lock serves no function, in this case. Java uses [recursive mutexes](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Reentrant_mutex), so a thread that holds a lock on a given mutex can lock it again, and a lock count is kept. Only when the last `synchronized` block is exited, is the mutex actually unlocked.

Comment: so if i understand in this case the lock object counter is set on 2. When the trhead leaves the inner block the counter is 1 and when it will leave the outer block the lock is free... i understand? thanks

Comment: i reed your link, and the link reply about my question. thank you so much Chris Jester-Young.

Comment: @Elliott Not to pick on you or anything, but given that recursive mutex (as mentioned in my answer) is just another name for reentrant mutex, I'm not sure what "additional info" your comment provides. :-)

Comment: My apologies if it didn't add anything else.